# Preset encoding for Search-in-Files Feature

Tags: search, encoding, notepad++

I have a huge Filedump to handle (7000+ Files) which are all encoded in OEM-US (and i need them to remain OEM-US or return to OEM-US when I'm done)

The search in files feature from Notepad++ would actually solve all my Problems. (It's a single use job - I don't want to bore you with the details but its about sanatizing old code which has partially been written in foreign languages like german or french including their notorious characters like äöüèéàç)

The thing is: Most of the time, Notepad++ detects the wrong encodings and different encodings for different files. Usually, it detects ANSI or UTF-8 but sometimes it get exotic and all of a sudden my files are supposed to be encoded in Shift-JIS or Big5 Which messes up my search terms as they sometimes turn different special chars into the same set of replacement chars.

So I'm looking for a way to either

a) Tell notepad++ which encoding to select for the "search in files" job i want to run.

b) convert all Files to UTF-8, run the search-replace job there and restore the encoding to OEM-US

or

c) Find a different Software to handle this issue for me

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/13950/set-default-character-set-for-opening-existing-files

Comment: ty this helps partially as the encoding is consistent now. Unfortunately I can't set the default coding to be used (and "remember session" only affects opened files. - and only the one that is open.) I can set the encoding for NEW files but the ones i open, even if i just saved and closed them in OEM-US open in ansi now. - If i can tell N++ to diverge from my systems encoding. I'm settled.